# Why would someone want to teleport the Moon away from our Solar system?

Tags: science-based, planets, science-fiction, alternate-worlds, alternate-reality

**Why would someone want to teleport the Moon away from our solar system?**

A glimpse of the future seen in a dream, reveals an ET race with a ship as big as the Moon, if not twice as big, that manages to create a black hole, or portal(the portal had a black tone spinning, in a clockwise rotation(if I remember correct)), that, after it's created, it takes both the Moon and their ship.
In the dream I was being aware of the individual's experience seeing this and the group that had it.
They had a technology to glimpse the future(precognition, visions) with the human mind and record the dreams or visions on the phone(a 5-6 inch screen more or less).
Long story short, in the visions, the Man sees two angry aliens, who were first seen as crying, while at the same time mad, and in their anger, they decide to take the Moon away.
The group is left contemplating as to the consequences of the Moon being gone and it's effects on the Earth, instead of why the ET race took the Moon in the first place.
In the visions, as the Moon was taken away, there were some symbols on it(a bird symbol, water symbols).

**The question is, what could possibly be so valuable on the Moon, that an ET race would simply teleport it away?

And if the Moon is not so valuable, was it with clear intent to create cataclysmic climate change on Earth?**

Also to note, the dream happened 3 days ago(18th august). A full solar eclipse is happening on 21th of August.
As for more details about the vision, here:

> *A journey of a man, managing to somehow go into a portal and get a glimpse of a future.
>
>   He watches as he sees the eye of a being
>   with gray like skin, like the aluminum-iron metal.  The eye looks
>   lizard like.
>
>   The faces have a portrait very similar to vikings,
>   or better yet, a very similar face to that of [Gimli](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Gimli) from Lord of the
>   Rings.
>
>   Also their geometrical face figure and facial hair can
>   also be compared to that of [Lingbao Tianzun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingbao_Tianzun), ie. one of the Supreme
>   Pure Ones. But without the long moustaches.
>
>   So you combine
>   geometrical face figure of Gimli and that of Yuanshi Tianzun or
>   Lingbao Tianzun to obtain their geometrical face figure.
>
>   At the
>   aspect, it is estimated they are 6 ft 3 in to 6 ft 6 in (1.91m-1.98m).
>   They have long beards, the color of their beards is gray/black.  They
>   have long lateral hair on the sides and may look bald in the center. 
>   They are in control of a big spaceship.
>
>   The spaceship has the
>   form of a cross with equal sides, but the long body is very thick.
>
>   The spaceship manages to create a big enough portal to take out the
>   Moon itself, and after that, both the spaceship and the Moon are gone.
>   Apparently, the individual had a phone that managed to record it's
>   dreams or memories of the vision. So everything he dreamed, it was on
>   his phone, the image of the alien, the aliens becoming angry and of
>   course them, taking the Moon.  After he wakes up, he is reassured that
>   everything he recorded is on the phone. He then talks to his team
>   about it, the Moon is still not gone, but, the team debates what bad
>   effects on the environment would be, if the Moon is gone. So then...
>   They debate the dream, the effects of Moon being gone, the disastrous
>   effects on the environment.
>
>   Why would some aliens, get mad at
>   what's happening in the world, open a portal and steal the Moon? Their
>   spaceship size is uncertain, but it can be as big as the Moon or twice
>   as that.
>
>   Also to note, there were some symbols flashing on the
>   Moon, before it was gone. The Moon had the symbols of the goose. The
>   Moon had some other similar symbols, like that of water.
>
>   Also,
>   other symbols can be noted(but are not remembered).*

Comment: Are you sure this question is fit for WorldBuilding? The way the title is phrased suggests it is not.

Comment: This question looks very opinion-based. I don't see how questions could be objectively rated against one another as you are asking about reasons for your characters to do something. Finding and explaining their motivation is your job as the author. This doesn't seem to be about WorldBuilding. Can you try to [edit] it to focus on somewhat objective aspects of WorldBuilding that we can help you with?

Comment: This is really hard to read, with all the parenthetical remarks and largely irrelevant background material on how you got the idea, but I'm leaning toward this being too much about opinion for us. "Why would someone want to perform action X?" is nearly impossible to answer objectively without knowing what their motivations are, and your question seems to jump from there being some resource on the Moon that these aliens desire, to intent to cause climate change on Earth (which I think is doubtful that it would happen, but that's another issue). All in all, I think we just don't know enough.

Comment: First of all, the question put is not in any way opinion-based. It is a narrative, and one main question, with a side question regarding that specific narrative. A question and an opinion are two different things. Second of all, if you want something 'opinion-based', here it is. This planet is good, it has both good people and not so good. And because of it, if a bunch of aliens would have to choose between teleporting away a moon or teleporting a bunch of irritated snowflakes away, then the more likely outcome, is teleporting those specific snowflakes away.

Answer (score 3):

The aliens saw that the humans were about to spread to the stars, and ultimatly, in the far future, would have triggered and win a war against their race. They couldn't let it happen, but at the same time they couldn't wipe out an entire sentient species, especially since they were still innocent of their future "crime". They saw that the Moon was our first hop, our bridgehead, and that it contained the easily accessible resources (namely Helium3) that would allow us to build interstellar spaceships.

So, after a brief argument between the aliens (*"We should destroy them ! - No, we ought to be better than them."*), they decide to take away our Moon. But since the very act of showing that intelligent life was out there could lead to a great boost in the efforts towards space research, they had to leave a message, a warning. However, their intelligence is far superior to ours. How would you communicate with ants ? So they keep it simple thinking we would understand.

**You are goose. Stay in water. Or else...**

*And the Moon disappears.*

Comment: A good response, for reminding people about 'Helium3'. Also a nice interpretation about 'goose', but my intuition tells me there's a treasure on the Moon, with bird related origins. Also, the more likely outcome in regards to the 'aliens' would be in a way disappointment in the human race leadership, probably. Too much lies in the media, too many fake wars and narratives and of course too many distractions disguised as entertainment. This answer, is likely to be opinion-based seen by other people. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid a cataclysmic event on *their* planet (or maybe to make a new planet they are trying colonise suitable for life), they need a satellite of a very particular size to orbit their planet.

After searching their galaxy, they've found that the moon is exactly the right size.

Why not simply build a satellite out of other smaller rocks? Teleporting planetoids is quite a big job, and either it's easier and more cost effective to take the entire thing in one go, or else maybe they can only use the teleporter once for some reason.

**Edit**

Somehow I missed the bit about the aliens being angry, so how about:

*It's their Moon!* (Or maybe they just think it is) They somehow think we stole it from them hundreds of thousands of years ago (or earlier) - which is possibly leading to the cataclysmic event on their planet mentioned above (or maybe not).

Maybe a large body passed near their planet, whisked the moon out into space with a gravitational catapult, and it eventually got captured by our planet's gravity and has been in orbit ever since.

Of course you might have to handwave all the evidence about the Moon having been created from a collision with Earth (though I'm not sure how strong that evidence is). Or maybe you wouldn't, if it turned out they were mistaken about it being their Moon.

Comment: The narrative points out anger and disappointment from the aliens, and that would be the reason they took that celestial object, doubt that someone with a ship that can take other interstellar objects could not find any other Moon from our solar system or any other star system.

Comment: So the Earthers caused the cataclysm on their world! And I meant that the Moon was just exactly the right size & specifications they need, which would be a lot more difficult to find than just any old rock.